# Why another instance method call doesn't run?

Tags: javascript, methods, instance, invoke

In my JavaScript, I have a `move()` method for the `Image` class, which is supposed to animate the instances of the `Image` class, when their `move()` method is called, with the argument of their numeric `id`s,

the first time, the method `Image1.move(1);` is called and it animates the first `Image` instance, in the `move()` method, however, I have declared the next instance to run the `move()` method with the argument of it's `id`, but except for the instance `Image1`, no other instances run the `move()` method called for, why does that happen? And how do I make other instances to run `move()` method, when being called?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
        let slidingChoices = {
            slideCount: 3,
            slidingDuration: 1000,
            slidePause: 2500,
        }
        let sliderWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-wrapper')[0];
        let sliderWrapperWidth = sliderWrapper.offsetWidth;
        class Image {
            constructor(_src, _id) {
                this.src = _src;
                this.id = _id;
                this.appear()
            }
            appear() {
                let img = document.createElement('img');
                img.setAttribute("src", this.src);
                img.id = this.id;
                img.classList.add('img');
                sliderWrapper.appendChild(img);
                img.style.left = `${sliderWrapperWidth}px`;
                img.onload = function() {
                    sliderWrapper.style.height = `${img.height}px`;
                }
                document.getElementById('1').style.left = '0';
            }
            move(which) {
                let NextImageNumber;
                window.onload = function() {  document.getElementById(which).style.left = '0px';
                    document.getElementById(which).style.transition =  slidingChoices.slidingDuration + 'ms';
                    if (document.getElementById(which).style.left === '0px') {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            document.getElementById(which).style.left = -sliderWrapperWidth + 'px';
                            document.getElementById(which).style.transition = slidingChoices.slidingDuration + 'ms';  document.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
                                document.getElementById(which).style.left = sliderWrapperWidth + 'px';
                                document.getElementById(which).style.transition = 'none';
                            });
                            // Here is the problem
                            NextImageNumber = (which + 1 < slidingChoices.slideCount ) ? which + 1 : 1;
                            eval(`Image${NextImageNumber}.move(${NextImageNumber})`);
                        },slidingChoices.slidePause)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= slidingChoices.slideCount; i++) {
            eval(`Image${i} = new Image('https://via.placeholder.com/200/FFFF00/000000?Text=WebsiteBuilders.com', '${i}')`);
        }
        Image1.move(1);

    });
```

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .slider-wrapper{
            position: relative;
            max-width: 200px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }
        .slider-wrapper img{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
        }
```

```html
<div class="slider-wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) is the name of a built in JS class, and in strict mode `eval` won't have access to your overwritten class, so it's calling the native image class instead of the one you defined and the native one doesn't have a `move` method. You should probably rename your class.

Also, `window.onload` isn't going to be called every time you call `move()`. That should be at the top level, not inside your move method.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer!